# Building a Facebook interface for an eye-gaze computer running Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook-graph-api

I am part of a senior design group looking to build an eye-gaze interface for Facebook on Windows 10. That is, my group has a client who controls his computer with his eyes and would like an easier way of accessing Facebook.

Of course we would like to allow our client to access all aspects of Facebook, most importantly Messaging and browsing his News Feed, but also commenting and replying to friends, posts, etc.

I have spent the last few weeks building test applications in Visual Studio, using Facebook's C# SDK and have found that, through it, many things are not accessible. Messaging and News Feed have been inaccessible from the start, but recently, after implementing and using a system that allowed me to comment on my own posts, this feature became unavailable as well.

My question is very broad and directly to Facebook Developers: Is there any way to accomplish my group's goal? (I realize that this may require more of a discussion, but I don't want to make this post too long.) What is the direction of the Graph API? We want to create a system that will last and requires as little maintenance as possible. (The recent removal of commenting makes me worried that our system would become unusable within a year if we used Graph API.)

*We are not looking to make any money from this endeavor. My group is creating this solely for academic purposes and are customizing this interface for a single "client" who is not compensating us in any way.

Thanks for taking the time to read this

Comment: Normal Graph API and permissions available to common 3rd-party apps won't do the trick. You'd have to find a way to reach out to Facebook developers directly (SO is not the place to do that) to inquire whether they have some sort of program/partnership to assist companies/developers dealing in that kind of stuff - but if so, my guess is you'd have to be a rather larger player to receive that, whereas your question rather sounds like you are focusing on one individual's needs. When I combine _"a client who controls his computer with his eyes and would like an easier way of accessing Facebook"_

Comment: [...] and _"We want to create a system that will last and requires as little maintenance as possible."_ - then my advice would probably be, try and see if that can't perhaps rather be achieved by giving them way to control their _web browser_ with their eyes, and let them use that to access Facebook (and, added bonus - other stuff) that way. [...]

Comment: [...] While their desktop version is not focused on accessibility much, if you show the mobile version https://m.facebook.com/ on a desktop screen(?), the reduced set of controls, larger buttons etc. could perhaps be of help to someone with limited abilities regarding "mouse-pointer" accuracy?